# How does Use Method finds next delegate in .net core middleware?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, middleware

I am confused how does next which is a Type of RequestDelegate finds The next delegate here?Like How does  await `next.Invoke(context)` invokes the following method ? I understand the same context is being passed as argument in next. but how does the next ordered method is invoked ?

```
var builder=WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app=builder.Build();    

app.Use(async (HttpContext context,RequestDelegate next) =>
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("HelloOne ");
    await next.Invoke(context);
});
app.Use(async (HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next) => {
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("HelloTwo");
    await next.Invoke(context);

});
app.Run();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, personally I’m not of the certain Microsoft calibre required to understand its mires of abstraction, indirection and general black magic but *in theory* you can [check out the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/) for yourself. Which is honestly pretty cool.

#### Registering the middlewares

Eventually all the `app.UseMyCoolMiddleware()` calls you put into your `Program.cs` end up at [`ApplicationBuilder.Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware)`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http/src/Builder/ApplicationBuilder.cs#L120):

```cs
//Adds the middleware to the application request pipeline.
public IApplicationBuilder Use(Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate> middleware)
{
    _components.Add(middleware);
    _descriptions?.Add(CreateMiddlewareDescription(middleware));

    return this;
}
```

You’ll notice that the middleware at this point is just a `Func`. This was generated in `UseMiddlewareExtensions.cs`, namely one of the overloads of [`UseMiddleware()`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/91102789da84a1e0b83b8b399f3352d315035efd/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/UseMiddlewareExtensions.cs#L48) (which then calls the above Use() method). In there is the voodoo that turns a middleware class/type into a `Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>`, by trying to find a method named “Invoke” and figuring out the dependencies to inject and so on.

If you scroll up in `ApplicationBuilder.cs` you’ll see that the “request pipeline” is just a plain old `List` of such `Func<RequestDelegate, RequestDelegate>`s. A `RequestDelegate` is an async function that takes a `HttpContext` and returns nothing: exactly like a middleware’s Invoke method. These `Func`s are (basically) the middlewares’ constructors. They receive the following middleware’s Invoke method and return their own.

#### Building the pipeline

Now this is all just config stuff in your `Program.cs` that runs only once when the server starts. Calling `app.Run()` marks the pipeline setup as complete and prepares all the middlewares. If you have custom middlewares you can step through and see that this is the time when [their constructors are called in reverse order](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http/src/Builder/ApplicationBuilder.cs#L195). In the end a single `RequestDelegate` remains, which you’ll notice is called “app”. It’s the Invoke method of the initial middleware, i.e. the entry point of the pipeline.

#### Running it

Obviously this is where it gets interesting. How is the pipeline actually invoked per request? I have no idea, but somehow when Kestrel (?) receives a request, it creates a `HttpContext`, fills it with all the relevant stuff and gives it to the aforementioned initial middleware. This will then either do its thing and pass the `HttpContext` on to the next middleware, or call the next middleware and *then* do its thing, or both. Or it may be a so-called “short-circuit” middleware, such as the one for serving static files. If it finds the requested file, the following middlewares for routing, auth etc. don’t need to run.

Good luck, lol.

Comment: great information buddy. thank you so much :)

Answer (score -1):

For understanding next.Invoke(context), it is good to know more about ASP.Net Core Middleware.

Based on [ASP.Net Core Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) ():

> Middleware is software that's assembled into an app pipeline to handle
> requests and responses. Each component:
>
> Chooses whether to pass the request to the next component in the
> pipeline. Can perform work before and after the next component in the
> pipeline. Request delegates are used to build the request pipeline.
> The request delegates handle each HTTP request.
> In other words, you inject a request delegate into the middleware and you have a choice to proceed in the path with calling Next method or not.

[image]

The following picture, depicts the request processing pipeline and the order of custom delegates.
[image]

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.